# Joining 2 SQL Queries from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm new to SQL so apologies for the noob question. I have searched other articles but can't seem to find something that works with my issue...

Essentially I have 2 tables (DOCMASTER, DOSHISTORY), as you may have guessed this a query to our DMS. Essentially a user wants a report about a certain set of documents numbers (these are template documents) with the following information;
- Created date
- Last accessed
- Last Modified
- Document number (unique id)

I can get the above info with the 2 queries below;

CREATED DATE + LAST MODIFIED DATE (from the DOCMASTER table)

```
SELECT [DOCNAME],[DOCNUM],[EDITWHEN] as 'last edited date',[ENTRYWHEN] as 'created date'
FROM [Knowledge_Prod].[MHGROUP].[DOCMASTER]
where DOCNUM in ('10098776', '1355264')
```

LAST ACCESSED DATE (from the DOCHISTORY table)

```
SELECT DOCNUM, MAX (ACTIVITY_DATETIME) as 'last accessed date'
FROM [Knowledge_Prod].[MHGROUP].[DOCHISTORY]
WHERE ACTIVITY in ('View','Create','Copy', 'Checkin', 'Checkout','Print','Mail')
  and DOCNUM in ('10098776', '1355264')
Group by DOCNUM
```

What would be the best way to join these queries based on the DOCNUM to compile the results together to look like;

DOCNUM - last accessed date - last edited date - created date

Thankyou in advance for your assistance this has been crushing my soul for the last few hours. ALSO I am using SMSS for all my querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since we don't have test data to test and below is one safest way

```
;with cte
as
(
SELECT [DOCNAME],[DOCNUM],[EDITWHEN] as 'last edited date',[ENTRYWHEN] as 'created date'
    FROM [Knowledge_Prod].[MHGROUP].[DOCMASTER]
    where DOCNUM in ('10098776', '1355264')
)
,cte1 as
(
 SELECT DOCNUM, MAX (ACTIVITY_DATETIME) as 'last accessed date'
      FROM [Knowledge_Prod].[MHGROUP].[DOCHISTORY]
      WHERE ACTIVITY in ('View','Create','Copy', 'Checkin', 'Checkout','Print','Mail') and DOCNUM in ('10098776', '1355264')
      Group by DOCNUM)
select * from cte c join cte1 c1
on c1.docnum=c.docnum
```

Comment: You're a legend..! I will have to lookup how you did this as it is brilliant. Appreciate the swift response! - Will accept as soon as the min time is up. Thanks a bunch

Comment: GLad it helped you,i recommend to take a look at this link for future questions,it enables to test and also you may get upvotes as well:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Excellant thanks for the tip! I will be sure to implement in my next question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [DOCNAME],[DOCNUM],[EDITWHEN] as 'last edited date',[ENTRYWHEN] as 'created date', MAX (ACTIVITY_DATETIME) as 'last accessed date'
FROM [Knowledge_Prod].[MHGROUP].[DOCMASTER] dm
    INNER JOIN [Knowledge_Prod].[MHGROUP].[DOCHISTORY] dh
    ON dm.DOCNUM = dh.DOCNUM
WHERE dm.DOCNUM in ('10098776', '1355264')
AND dh.ACTIVITY in ('View','Create','Copy', 'Checkin', 'Checkout','Print','Mail')
GROUP BY [DOCNAME],[DOCNUM],[EDITWHEN],[ENTRYWHEN]
```